# Image Browser not working in CkEditor on Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, ckeditor, ckfinder

In my CkEditor upload image works fine but browse image not working. I integrated CkFinder on to it.

My Razor view:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/CKEditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/CKEditor/ckfinder/ckfinder.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Content, new { @id = "ckeditor" })

CKEDITOR.replace('ckeditor',
{
    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '/Scripts/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images',
    filebrowserUploadUrl: '/Scripts/ckfinder/core/connector/aspx/connector.aspx?   command=QuickUpload&type=Files',
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/ImageUploader/UploadImage'     
}
```

For Image upload i used an action it works fine .But Image Browser not works properly.
It redirects to ckfinder but not showing Uploaded images also not showing folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Used Filemanager for browseing Image instead of ckfinder

In my view

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Content, new { @id = "ckeditor" })


CKEDITOR.replace('ckeditor',
{

 filebrowserImageUploadUrl:'/ImageUploader/UploadImage',//for uploading image 
 filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '/Scripts/FileManager/index.html'

 }
);
```

Download Filemanager for ckeditor and specify the folder path in filemanager.aspx.cs inside connector it works great